# Validate custom directive using ngMessages

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation, ng-messages

I writing a web app in angularjs and using [angular material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/) (not sure if that is relevant to the question) and [ngMessages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) to provide feedback for invalid inputs to the user.

Usually, for validation of directives provided, I can validate in a way similar to:

```
<md-input-container>
    <input required name="myInput" ng-model="someModel">
    <div ng-messages="formName.myInput.$error">
        <div ng-message="required">This field is required.</div>
    </div> 
</md-input-container>
```

But if I created my own custom directive...

```
moduleName.directive('ngCustomdir', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel){
            //do some validation
            return validation; //<--true or false based on validation
        }
    };
}
```

and include it in my input...

```
<input required ng-customdir name="myInput" ng-model="someModel">
```

I know it validates the input, because if the input is invalid based on my custom directive's validation, the field turns red and the $invalid value is set to true, but I do not know how to make a message appear with ngMessages based on when this happens.

```
<div ng-messages="formName.myInput.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">This field is required.</div>
    <div ng-message="customdir">This is what I need to appear.</div>
</div>
```

I cannot seem to get a message to appear when my custom directive validation is invalid.  How do I do this?
Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are getting very close, just add some validation in your `link` function:

```
link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel){
        ngModel.$validators.required = function(modelValue) {
              //true or false based on required validation
        };

        ngModel.$validators.customdir= function(modelValue) {
              //true or false based on custome dir validation
        };
    }
```

When the model changes, AngularJS will call all the validate functions in `$validators` object. The ng-message will display based on the function name.
More infomation about the $validators:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/11/exploring-angular-1.3-validators-pipeline.html

Comment: I have found very useful your comment. I could not find that name had to have the ng-messages. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is more compact alternative to Huy's solution:

```
link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel){
    //validation true or false
    ngModel.$setValidity('required',validation);

    ngModel.$setValidity('customdir',validation);
}
```